# Using setInterval with $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am trying to invoke a function after the loading of the html page. Its working fine and I want the function to be invoked after every 3 seconds and hence inserted the setInterval() for it. But the function is not at all getting called. Is there any problem with the syntax of setInterval()..?

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready( setInterval(function(){f()},3000); );

function f()
{
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET","/anu/get.php",true);
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(xhttp.readyState==4){
var Display = document.getElementById('new');
Display.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
}

}

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="new"> </p>

<body>

</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval(function(){f()},3000);` is a very long winded way of saying: `setInterval(f,3000);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function(){f()},3000);
});
```

The problem here is that `setInterval` [returns a number](http://developers.whatwg.org/timers.html#timers), and passing a number to `$(document).ready(...)` does nothing. Instead, you need to pass `$(document).ready(...)` a function, such as a function that starts off the `setInterval` call.

The other problem is that you included a semicolon after the `setInterval`, but semicolons are only valid on statements (which you can think of as "things that stand on their own line"). You can only pass *expressions* to functions like `setInterval`, and expressions don't have semicolons, so your extra semicolon before the closing parenthesis is an error, because the JS engine sees a semicolon-terminated statement where it expects there to be a no-semicolon expression.

---

Also, you can shorten this to just

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(f, 3000);
});
```

or even

```
$(function () {
  setInterval(f, 3000);
});
```