# JavaScript refresh script broken

Tags: javascript, php

Here I have small JavaScript to refresh my included page every x second. On WAMP localhost works perfectly but when uploaded on Linux server doesn't work.

JavaScript Code

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){   
            $("#weather").load("include/page.php");
        }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function

Comment: why is it in an [html comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#html_comments)?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458544/2457222) answer your question?

Comment: Hello @AidanHakimian unfortunately it doesn't help!

Comment: Can you please tell me which version of jQuery you are using? Perhaps include the script in your post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have included jQuery twice. Thank You All

Answer (score -1):

Refresh page every second with meta

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
```

or with javascript

```
setInterval(function() {
  window.location.reload();
}, 1000);
```